SQL no me importa datos con decimales desde un archivo CSV
estoy intentado de conectar un archivo CSV a SQL, (usando SSMS).
El archivo CSV genera unas columnas con números decimales (tiene punto como separador decimal) que he probado cambiar el tipo de datos a float, real, decimal(18,10) pero ninguno de estos me muestra al hacer las consultas los números decimales correctamente.
SSMS está en inglés, y supuse que tomaría bien los datos, al ser en inglés el separador decimal generalmente es el punto... pero no está funcionando...

La conexión con el archivo CSV lo hago de la siguiente manera, importando un archivo "plano": y luego modifico el tipo de dato por campo.


El archivo CSV, muestra la siguiente vista previa, se ven correctamente los números decimales (abriendo en formato texto) :

Datos que no si si afectan a esto o no, instalé SQL Server 2022 versión Express, pero ahora dudo si debería haber instalado la versión Developer...

Que tipo de dato estas usando para las columnas?

Están en float @alanfcm

Muestra el archivo en formato de texto, no en formato de excel. También muestra la configuración que estás usando para importar.

Actualizado el post @LuisCazares

Según lo que se alcanza a ver y generando el archivo por mi cuenta para cargarlo en mi bd de pruebas, no se puede replicar el error. Es probable que el punto que estás usando es un caracter diferente.

Puedo subir el drive de los archivos, así intentas replicarlo igual que yo, esto que estoy haciendo es un tutorial de Youtube para portafolio de Data Analyst. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17U0ah6Q4MJM_wIn_Xl4fHc-1fO6Q4s6z

Una opción es realizar tu importación con la sentencia BULK INSERT de SQL.
Es importante considerar que tu tabla debe tener la misma estructura que tu archivo en cuanto a numero de columnas.
BULK INSERT #TuTabla
FROM 'Ruta del archivo'
WITH(
    FIRSTROW = 2, --Esto por si tu primer linea es el encabezado de tu tabla
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a')


El problema con esto es que necesita un archivo de formato para identificar las comillas como delimitador de la columna de ingredientes.

Tienes razón, no había prestado atención a su layout.

Intenté reproducir el error. Sin embargo, siguiendo los pasos que indicas no tengo ningún problema.
Te dejo un respaldo de una base de datos solo con esa tabla para que puedas trabajar en tu proyecto. Lo puedes restaurar con esta instrucción
RESTORE DATABASE [Pizza_Sales_DB] FROM  DISK = N'C:\RutaDelRespaldo\Pizza_Sales_DB.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

El respaldo lo encuentras aquí.

Siguiendo tu instrucción, me devuelve: "Error de sistema operativo 5 (Acceso denegado.)." Debo verificar algo antes de esto?

Verifica que la ruta sea correcta y que el servidor tenga acceso a la misma.

Por primero: Tu pregunta tiene la etiqueta MySQL y dices que usas SSMS. Entonces, ¿estás usando MySQL con SSMS? ¿Usando un Linked Server? ¿Por qué? ¿Por qué no usas una herramienta hecha para MySQL si usas MySQL?
Otra cosa son los formatos. Tus fechas tienen el formato 01-02-2024. ¿Cuál es el día y cuál es el mes? Probablemente lo sabes, pero ¿sabe tu herramienta de importar datos? Y con números: ¿Cuál es el separador decimal? Parece que para tu aplicación no es el punto como supones. Y no puede ser deseado que el resultado es un FLOAT, un tipo aproximado, en vez de un tipo preciso como DECIMAL.
Realmente, no conozco tu herramienta para importar el CSV, pero debe ser posible estipular los formatos. (Si no lo es, ¡no uses esta herramienta!) Busca esta opción, para decir a la herramienta que tu formato de fechas es dd-mm-yyyy, que el separador decimal es el punto y que no quieres resultados en tipos de datos aproximados.

He intentado con varias formas de importación que permite SSMS, y con respecto a las etiquetas, disculpe , soy nueva por aquí

Más que una respuesta, esto es un comentario.
